Why Sinter is using so much memory? Is there a way to reduce it?
I am using Sinter to sample STIM circuit of a big Hypergraph product code [[1800,98,10]]. The machine I am using has 128GB ram and 32 CPU cores. Sinter is eating up huge memory and it crashes in a while, making it very difficult to finish the sampling. Sometimes it crashes after taking like 50 shots. Why does it uses so much memory? Is there any way to reduce it?

How are you decoding it?

I am using BPOSD decoder with overlapping window.

When you run that decoder on a shot, how much memory does it consume while running? Does the sinter.Decoder that you're exposing it with implement the compile_decoder_for_dem method so the shots can be streamed?

A single core can easily consume upto 30-40GB of memory. I am not entirely sure about the second part of your question. It converts .dem file to a matrix and performs Gaussian inversion on reduced columns based on belief propagation outcome.

We notice that the memory usage keeps increasing as more and more shots are decoded. Does that mean some data is being stored in the memory that is not used later?

My guess is that it's something wrong with the class you are using for decoding; the thing that inherits sinter.Decoder that you are telling sinter about via the "custom_decoders" argument. Try testing that class on its own and see if it leaks memory.

I kind of understand what you are trying to say but I am not sure how to test it. Could you explain in a simpler way?

Test your decoder by itself, without involving sinter, so that there are fewer things going on and it's easier to debug. This is a key programming skill: when something is going wrong but you don't know why, see if it still goes wrong in a simpler situation.
